# php array_map removes more than required

Tags: php, array-map

I have an array like the following . . .

```
Array
(
    [code] => BILL
    [assets] => Array
        (
            [en] => Array
                (
                    [labels] => Array
                        (
                            [datestamp] => April 30, 2013
                        )

                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [Equity] => 88.83000000000
                            [Global] => 10.84000000000
                            [Other] => 0.33099095766
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I have run the array_map function on this array to remove the `[en]` array

```
$en = array_map(function ($e){ return $e['en']; } , $en );
```

note how the resulting array has truncated the value for `[code]` from `BILL` to `B`

```
Array
(
    [code] => B
    [assets] => Array
        (
            [labels] => Array
                (
                    [datestamp] => April 30, 2013
                )

            [data] => Array
                (
                    [Equity] => 88.83000000000
                    [Global] => 10.84000000000
                    [Other] => 0.33099095766
                )

        )

)
```

Any tips on how to avoid that from happening.  It is removing the array with the key `[en]` as required, but I don't want the value for `[code]` to be truncated.

Thanks.

Comment: The index `'en'` will be cast to int (=> 0), when used to access a string by index. `BILL[0]` => `'B'`

Comment: Yes, it is treating the string like an array, Yoshi is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform type checking:

```
$en = array_map(function ($e){
    if (is_array($e)) {
        return $e['en'];
    } else {
        return $e;
    }
} , $en );
```

Although it might suffice to do just this:

```
$en['assets'] = $en['assets']['en'];
```

Comment: your 2nd idea is what I used, well sort of.  `$en_new['code'] = $en['code'];`  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello instead of passing entire array you mentioned as argument, you can pass the assets part of array as argument to array_map function :

```
$en_new = array_map(function ($e){ return $e['en']; } , $en['assets'] );
```

and then append the code part:

```
$en_new['code'] = $en['code'];
```